# undefined is not a function .filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

I'm trying to make a search input setting the state "search" in the onChangeText

```
 <TextInput
          label="Pesquisar"
          theme={{
            colors: {
              primary: "white",
              text: "white",
              placeholder: "white",
              underlineColor: "transparent",
            },
          }}
          value={search}
          onChangeText={setSearch}
         />
```

so I'm getting an array of objects from axios and then i set it into another state

```
const [cars, setCars] = useState([])
```

In the console.log i did i got these values:

```
data Array [
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6316364fdd41d96a9df444",
    "image": "https://i.ibb.co/C51M22C/8bcc6f8cb09bba25780f2506c85c9635.jpg",,
    "model": "240",
    "name": "Car 1",
    "price": 99999999,
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6316364fdd41d96a9dff54cb",
    "image": "https://i.ibb.co/C51M22C/8bcc6f8cb09bba25780f2506c85c9635.jpg",,
    "model": "200",
    "name": "Car 2",
    "price": 99999999,
   }
]
```

But when I try to use a filter function and then a .map into this function to show the array of cars, it gives this error:
`"undefined is not a function (near '...filteredCars.map')"`

the filteredCar function:

```
const filteredCars = () => {
    cars.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    });
  };
```

here is where i call the filter function inside a .map

````
const carsItems = filteredCar.map((item) => {
    return (
      <View key={item._id}>
        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity key={item} activeOpacity={0.8}>
            <Card
              style={{
                marginLeft: 15,
                marginRight: 15,
                marginTop: 0,
                borderRadius: 10,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.push("Details", {
                  id: item._id,
                  name: item.name,
                });
              }}
            >
              <Card.Cover
                source={{ uri: item.imagem_principal }}
                style={{ margin: 5, borderRadius: 10 }}
              />
              <Card.Content>
                <Title>{item.name}</Title>
                <Paragraph>{item.model}</Paragraph>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Divider />
      </View>
    );
  });```
Does anyone know why i'm getting this error?
````

Comment: Where is your code that calls `filteredCars.map`?

Comment: does your filteredCar function return the result of cars.filter?

Comment: How can I see that? @Bergmann

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` returns a *new* array, it doesn't modify the old one. So calling it without returning or assigning the result to a variable doesn't do anything.

Comment: well we can't see the full function body of filteredCars function. but to me it seems like - from what i see - it's missing a return statement

Comment: So, using the return before item.name.toLowerCase().. did not work?

Comment: the return does work. but it's generating a new array. question is if you return that new array

Comment: add a return before cars.filter. your function doesn't return the result of the filter

Comment: How can I do that? @s

Comment: `const filteredCars = () => {
    return cars.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    });
  };`

Comment: I changed the code but still returning the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the comments, I now understand what your issue is. You're using `filteredCars` as a function and then want to iterate over it with `.map`. Remove the function body around the whole thing.

You were assigning a function to your `const filteredCars` instead of the array from the `cars.filter` result.

This:

```
const filteredCars = () => {
    return cars.filter(...filterFunction)
}
```

is assigning a function to your const. As such, you had to call it first to get an array of your filtered cars.

```
const cars_filtered = filteredCars();
```

Then you could've mapped over `cars_filtered`.

Use:

```
const filteredCars = cars.filter((item) => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
});
```

instead.